# phoenix_ecto : error when loading assoc

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

With the following mix deps :

```
[{:phoenix, "~> 0.15"},
 {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 1.0.0"},
 {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
 {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.1"},
 {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 0.5", only: :dev},
 {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}]
```

And the following models :

```
# foo.ex
has_many: :bars, App.Bar

# bar.ex
belongs_to: :foo, App.Foo
```

I have an error when trying to preload `bars`, when a `Foo` was already inserted in the database :

```
Repo.all(Foo) |> Repo.preload(:bars)
```

yields :

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Postgrex.Extensions.Binary.encode/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/preloader.ex:49: Ecto.Repo.Preloader.do_preload/4
```

It yields no error (just `[]`) when no `Foo` has been inserted yet.

`Bar` migration :

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreateBar do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:bars) do
      add :title, :string
      add :foo_id

      timestamps
    end

    create index(:bars, [:foo_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the type of `:foo_id` in your migration.

Try the following:

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreateBar do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:bars) do
      add :title, :string
      add :foo_id, references(:foos)

      timestamps
    end

    create index(:bars, [:foo_id])
  end
end
```

You can read the docs for the migrations at http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/0.15.0/Ecto.Migration.html

Comment: I already specified it in the code, my bad for not having put it here, just wanted to describe the relation, edited accordingly.

Comment: Could you please post your migration too? This error can happen when the foreign key is incorrect.

Comment: Updated with the migration.

Comment: I think you need to specify the type (integer) for the foo_id field.